# controlling audio speed/play back rate with soundjs

Tags: javascript, html, soundjs

does anyone know how can I change the speed of music by soundjs?

```
    createjs.Sound.registerSound("{mp3 address}", "src1");
    createjs.Sound.play("src1");
```